# Does "< />" mean anything in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, stack, variable-declaration

Now, I know that StackOverflow is not a place to ask for help on homework, but this question has me completely stumped. I showed it to my friends and they are just as confused as I am.

I had two attempts for this question, I tried with none of the answers selected and I was marked wrong, and I tried with just the 3rd one selected and I was marked wrong. So this isn't about getting credit, as I've already lost credit for it, but I just want to understand what this question is.

As far as I can tell, none of these answers are even valid Java, let alone things that would produce the intended result. Does `< />` mean anything in Java? I've never seen it before. Does it have anything to do with the diamond operator?

[image: what even]

Comment: No, it doesn't mean anything. It is a problem with how they are rendering the content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a display issue in the website of your multiple choices question.
`/>` is supposed to display `>` so `</>` is simply `<>`, the [diamond operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond).

---

By the way, I think that there is no correct answer since the [only constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html#%3Cinit%3E()) of `Stack` takes no parameters, so there is no way to initialize the stack with a size of 50. It actually doesn't even make sense, you could theoretically initialize a stack with a given **capacity** (size of the backing array), but for a stack to have a **size** of 50, it needs to hold 50 elements.
So selecting no answer should be the only correct way. Or this test is not about `java.util.Stack` but about a custom Stack class.

Comment: None of the answers seem to be valid Java if I remove the ` /` from them.

Comment: If this is the case, then none of them are correct, because `Stack studentNames` is a raw type.

Comment: @AndyTurner : well since its written *that can hold Strings* and not *that must only hold Strings*, I assume that a raw type Stack is correct. However, there is only one constructor in Stack which takes no parameter, so there is no way to do what the question asks.

Comment: Good to know I'm not crazy then, so it's just a problem with the question. I *did* try checking none of the boxes and I was marked wrong for that.